# How do you print an error message when trying to enter a negative value into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How to print an error message in Java when data is being entered into an array.

### Code:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
     System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
     columns = keyboard.nextInt();
     bandstand[rows] = new double [columns];
     while ( columns < 0){
         System.out.print ("ERROR: Out of range, try again:");
         columns = keyboard.nextInt();
     }

 }
```

### Exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException.`

Comment: Check the value of columns before creating your array.

Comment: Either explicitly check the value before you use it, or catch the exception and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options as far as specifics go, but for the most part they all involve simply checking that the value of `columns` makes sense *prior* to creating the array (your primary mistake is trying to create the array *before* trying to re-prompt for valid input). For example, you could, say, repeatedly prompt the user for input:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
    do {
        System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
        columns = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (columns < 0);
    ...
```

Or, if a special error message is desired, much like you have now:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
    System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
    columns = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (columns < 0) {
        System.out.print ("ERROR: Out of range, try again:");
        columns = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    ...
    // note that array is created *after* columns is validated
```

You could also accomplish a similar thing (given your current logic), by doing:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
    System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
    columns = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (columns < 0) {
        System.out.println("Columns must be >= 0!");
        continue; // starts over for this row
    }
    ...
```

The general goal is to ensure that no matter what, *by the time the array is created*, `columns >= 0`.

You could also catch the `NegativeArraySizeException` then go back and ask again, but I'd recommend against this in this situation primarily because your code will be a little more complicated (go ahead, try it as an exercise). In the general case, this approach has a few problems too; for example by the time the exception thrown you know that `columns` is negative but you don't know *why* -- you have more information at the time the value is input than you do at the time the value is incorrectly used (more important in more complex programs), and thus you can handle the error in a more meaningful way (e.g. print an error and prompt for input again), among other reasons which are outside the scope here.

Comment: Agreed. I think it's be a great idea to use a `try` and `catch` block as an exercise. _Word of advice ->_ Make sure you understand this code **very** well before doing so. I've met many a programmer that moved too fast and wasn't solid with the underlying concepts. Eventually they always run into something that shakes apart what they thought they understood in the beginning. Don't take this as discouragement, however you should be careful with your pacing. It'll help you in the end, I promise. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply moving the `while` loop before the line that sets `bandstand[rows]` will accomplish what I think you want:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
     System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
     columns = keyboard.nextInt();
     while ( columns < 0){
         System.out.print ("ERROR: Out of range, try again:");
         columns = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
     bandstand[rows] = new double [columns];

 }
```

When the `while` loop is complete, you will be certain that `columns >= 0` and therefore the `new double[columns]` will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (rows = 0; rows < bandstand.length; rows++){
 System.out.print ("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rows + (int) 'A'));
 columns = keyboard.nextInt();
 if(columns >= 0) { 
     bandstand[rows] = new double [columns];
  }
 while ( columns < 0){
     System.out.print ("ERROR: Out of range, try again:");
     columns = keyboard.nextInt();
 }

}
}
```

Check to see if columns is bigger or equal to zero before inserting into the array.

However your next `while` statement's logic seems incorrect.

Comment: Sorry the if() break wasn't appropriate earlier.

Comment: This still doesn't make much sense; you're not creating `bandstand[rows]` after getting new input.

Comment: @JasonC you're correct I wasn't looking too closely at his code just the logic he was asking about